# Не выполняется программа Python, Enter approximity and click enter: после ввода точности , больше ничего не выводится

Tags: python, оптимизация

```
#Реализация оптимизационного алгоритма методом парабол

import math
import random
def I(t):
  return math.cos(t)*math.exp(-t**2/2)
def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
#Вычисляет приближенное значение интеграла с помощью формулы трапеций
#   f - подынтегральная функция
    #a, b - пределы интегрирования#
    #n - количество частичных отрезков

    H = float(b - a)/n
    result = 0.5*(f(a) + f(b))
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += f(a + i*H)
    result *= H
    return result
I=trapezoidal(I,0,1,100)
def f(s):
  return (math.fabs((-I+s)*math.exp(1/2)))**1.5

eps=float(input(" Enter approximity and click enter:"))

h=0.001  #определяем шаг для метода
x0=random.uniform(0,1)
x=[0.05,0.1,0.5] 
m=1
#в цикле получаем выпуклую тройку точек x1,x2,x3
while (f(x[2])-f(x[1]))<0 or (f(x[0])-f(x[1]))<0 or (f(x[2])+f(x[0])-2*f(x[1]))<=0:
  if f(x0+h)<f(x0):
    x[0]=x0+2**(m-1)*h
    x[1]=x0+2**(m)*h
    x[2]=x0+2**(m+1)*h
  else:
    x[0]=x0-2**(m-1)*h
    x[1]=x0-2**(m)*h
    x[2]=x0-2**(m+1)*h
    m+=1
k=0
while math.fabs(f(x[1])-f(x[0]))>eps:
  f1=f(x[0])
  f2=f(x[1])
  f3=f(x[2])
  a1=(f2-f1)/(x[1]-x[0])
  a2=((f3-f1)/(x[2]-x[0])-(f2-f1)/(x[1]-x[0]))/(x[2]-x[1])
  x4=(x[0]+x[1])/2-a1/(2*a2) #нахождения вершины
  f4=f(x4)
  x.append(x4) #добавление в список точки х4
  x.sort(key=f) #сортировка точек
  if f(x[2])-f(x[1])>=0 and f(x[0])-f(x[1])>=0 and f(x[2])+f(x[0])-2*f(x[1])>0:
     x.remove(x[3])
  else:
     x.remove(x[2])
  k+=1
xmin=x[0]
print("xmin =",xmin)
print("f = ",[f(x[0]), f(x[1]), f(x[2])])
print("Number of iteration:",k)
```

Comment: Какие были вводные данные?

Comment: Точность вычисления eps вводится только

Comment: ну просто у вас начинается рекурсия. И это начинается не во всех случаях потому что у вас рандомно выводится `x0`

Comment: Я делал x0 не рандомным, результата нет

Comment: Точность не может быть больше 100%. Вы случайно не вводите eps > 1? :)

Comment: @Tihon Я в курсе, что не может, конечно же не ввожу )